# Why NinePatch dont work in LibGDX?

Tags: android, libgdx, nine-patch

I have a backround for message item, I want to make it stretched depending on the text. But when i make this:

```
    Drawable drawableButtonMessageUp = new TextureRegionDrawable(new TextureRegion(new Texture("data/message_my_g.9.png")));
    ButtonStyle buttonStyleMessage = new ButtonStyle();
    buttonStyleMessage.up = drawableButtonMessageUp;
    Button buttonMessage = new Button(buttonStyleMessage);
    Label labelMessage = new Label("", new LabelStyle(game.fonts[0], new Color(0, 0, 0, 1)));
    buttonMessage.add(labelMessage);
```

Background does not NinePath, it strached like a normal picture:
My result:
[image]

I want (example):
[image]

Backround for item:
[image]

I checked the nine patch picture in Android SDK, and this work good, how i can do this in libGDX?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you're not using a NinePatch, you're using a TextureRegion

you probably are going to want to change the line

```
Drawable drawableButtonMessageUp = new TextureRegionDrawable(new TextureRegion(new Texture("data/message_my_g.9.png")));
```

to something like

```
Drawable drawableButtonMessageUp = new NinePatchDrawable(new NinePatch(new Texture("data/message_my_g.9.png"), 1, 1, 1, 1));
```

Note that the number "1" here is a placeholder. You may need to play around with those numbers to get the ninepatch to look right.

For more information, please take a look at the documentation, particularly the section on [instantiating ninepatches](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Ninepatches#creating-and-instantiating-a-ninepatch-manually)